# Replacement Interval for Carbon or Charcoal Canister

Tags: emissions

How often should the Carbon or Charcoal Canister for most vehicles be replaced?

Comment: Please add more specificity to your question (e.g., make, model, year).  "Most vehicles" is a little too broad.

Comment: I personally have a 1997 Ford Ranger, but if I change the question to match my particular needs, the question might lose some usefulness.  Would it have been better if I had asked the following instead: "What is the average lifespan of a Charcoal Canister?"

Comment: I stand corrected (based on Paul's answer below).  "How often" == "Basically never."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring an accident which might damage a canister, it should last the life of the vehicle.